# Pink model on blender

Tags: modeling

my name is Mackenson, I am a beginner on blender and I have a problem and I would need help please. I learned about the internet and even on your site about the pink model. It explains to me that you have to go to external data, then find missing file. I followed, but I'm getting error messages. I show you my zip file, where the source of the model comes from. Also, I tried to click on the viewport shading button, but nothing happened. In the screenshot, it's at the top right. In short, I send you 5 screenshots to better understand my problem. My actions are framed in red. Help please [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: how i send 5 screenshot please

Comment: I am using version 2.83 of blender

Comment: If you want to post your screenshots, edit your question and click the add image button at the top. See here - https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1083/75504

Comment: You need to unzip the folder first, I think. In your third screenshot choose "Extraire vers" (Extract) and then choose this folder when looking for missing files

Comment: I "Extraire vers" (Extract) , what files please, explain step by step please

Comment: You can choose wherever you want to extract, but you have to remember the location. I don't use winrar so I don't know what is next but it should ask you for a location on your drive. Then you just have to tell that folder location to blender when it asks for missing files

Comment: i will try it, one sec

Comment: oh my god, i love you. It was very difficult for me. I send a screenshot that shows with arrows that I unzipped, as you told me. This could probably help other people Thank you, problem solved